# Trying to return multiple values to the calling function but it doesnt work

Tags: python, function

How can I return multiple values from `setGen()`?

```
def menu():
    option = int(input("Please select an option: \n 1: Set Generation 0 Values \n 2: View Generation 0 Values \n 3: Run Model"))

    if option == 1:
        setGen()
    elif option == 2:
        displayGen()
    elif option == 3:
        runModel(juveniles,adults,seniles)#,jSrate,aSrate,sSRate,bRate,endGeneration)
    elif option == 4:
        print(adults)
    menu()


def setGen():
    #enter number of juveniles
    juveniles = int(input("How many juveniles are in the total popluation?"))
    #enter number of adults
    adults = int(input("How many Adults are in the total popluation?"))
    #enter number of seniles
    seniles = int(input("How many Seniles are in the total popluation?"))
    #enter juvenilesenile survival rates
    return(juveniles,adults,seniles)

menu()
```

I can't think of a way to run the menu again when the function runs through and also the variables don't seem to return to the calling function

Answer (score 0):

In option 1 you are calling `setGen()` but you aren't assigning the return value(s) of that function to variables, so you are losing the data. Try changing that line to

`juveniles,adults,seniles = setGen()`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help

Comment: care to expound on that?